# Rails controller not calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I need one of my Rails controllers to call a Javascript (Coffeescript) function after create in order to pass the id of the new object created. The problem is that the function is never called.

Here's the controller comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    newcomment = Comment.create!(comment: params[:comment], user_id: current_user.id, rutina_id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :js => "create_comment(" + newcomment.id.to_s + ");" }
    end
  end
  ...
```

And my CoffeeScript file rutinas.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $('#dias').change ->
    ...

  $('#diasedit').change ->
    ...

  $('[id^="arrowUp"]').click ->
    ...

  $('[id^="arrowDown"]').click ->
    ...

  $('[id^="eliminar_com_"]').click ->
    ...

  $('[id^="editar_com_"]').click ->
    ...

  create_comment = (id) ->
    console.log(id)
    newComment = $('#com_model').clone();
    newComment.removeClass('hidden');
    newComment.find("td#content_com_model").html($('#comment').val());

    today = new Date();
    dd = today.getDate();
    mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10)
      dd = '0'+dd
    if(mm<10)
      mm = '0'+mm
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    newComment.find("small#date_com_model").html(today);

    newComment.find("small#date_com_model")

    newComment.insertAfter($('#com_model'))


  $('#printBtn').click ->
    ...


  if document.getElementById("rutinas-list") != null
    i = 0
    while i < document.getElementById("rutinas-list").childElementCount
      i += 1
      do(i) ->
        ...

  cambia_voto =(element, cambio) ->
    ...


  $("#rutina_privacy_lvl").change ->
    ...
```

The newcomment is successfully created and newcomment.id.to_s contains the right value, I've checked it, but console.log(id) is never reached.

**UPDATE**

`remote: true` is set in the form. In fact, i've tested

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
        logger.debug "create_comment(" + newcomment.id.to_s + ");"
        render :js => "create_comment(" + newcomment.id.to_s + ");"
    }
end
```

And `create_comment(41);` is correctly logged in ruby's terminal

Comment: i think you should have `create.js.erb` file where you can get `newcomment`

Comment: Have a look to network inspector in your browser. If still strange, paste it here.

Comment: Please paste complete js.coffee file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code from controller will execute when the request to action `create` is a JS request:

```
format.js { render :js => "create_comment(" + newcomment.id.to_s + ");" }
```

If you are using AJAX to send this request, then a possible mistake could be wrong value of `dataType` parameter. You need it set to "script" to make this JS work.

And if you are not calling the AJAX manually (using `remote: true`), then try writing this JS code in a .js.erb template.

Comment: That was for if you are not using `remote: true`

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console after creating a comment?

Comment: Is the function `create_comment` defined? Can you call it from browser console?

Comment: No, any error on the firefox browser console when creating, but if I try to call the function from the console it does show an error 

    `ReferenceError: create_comment is not defined`

Comment: Paste the complete JS file in question please.

Comment: Done, i have omitted the content of the other methods because it's a huge file, if you need it let me know. All the other callbacks and functions work correctly, even `cambia_voto`, although I only call `cambia_voto` from inside the same JS.

Comment: your `create_comment` function is not global. You will need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are probably doing it the wrong way.

What you should do is use AJAX to create the comment (via POST request), then use AJAX's callbacks if the request succeeds to execute the JS function you want and use what the controller has returned (via `format.json` in the controller response).

See https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/jquery/ajax